# Git: Can't make changes to remote

Tags: git

I searched a good bit, have been asking peers for help, but I can't get this issue with git straight.

Essentially I edit, commit the edit, and push (or pull and push) and I get this error at the end of the push succeeding:

```
remote: A   views/search.jade
remtoe: A   ...more code files...
remote: Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files. <- But it's the remote     repo.. can't do this.

...then the host nodester successfully restarts the app...
\m/ Nodester out \m/
```

The changes are not reflected in the site.

Here is a gist of me creating a repo from scratch, and pushing to the repo, with all the commands I ran leading to the error:
https://gist.github.com/1980376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `post-receive` hook on the repo you are pushing to and that hook is cd'ing into your application path and doing a pull on another clone of your repo and this latter repo is having unmerged entries in it.

Fix the unmerged entries (`git reset --hard` to blow them away), or fix the hook - your application should not be deployed from a repo working directory.

Comment: ...To deploy on nodester you can only `git push`, so I can't do anything with the `post-receive` hook, and I don't have any unmerged entries in my local repo. In my gist, the code I pull down has no unmerged changes, it starts up and runs fine.

Anyway, I deleted the app, and started all fresh, so I'm going to mark yours as the answer regardless.